# Create a correlation matrix based on multiple column values with p-values in R

Tags: r, for-loop, correlation, p-value

I'm new to R and I'm trying to create a correlation matrix that will also include p-values.

The main issue I'm having is with computing correlations for specific numeric variables depending on the identity of three factors.

My data looks something like this

```
    data.frame(
      cond = c("low", "medium", "high"),
      group = c("gr1", "gr2", "gr3"),
      rand = c("yes", "no"),
      trial1 = rnorm(30),
      trial2 = rnorm(30))
```

I want to correlate trial1 and trial2 for each unique value in cond, group, and rand. Essentially, for each level of those factors, I would like to get an r- and p-value, and save them in a matrix.

I tried it the long way - extracting the observations that I want to correlate by using three logical tests like this`(df$cond == "low") & (df$group == 'gr1') & (df&rand == 'yes')`. This gave me what I needed but the code is very long and doesn't save the values in a matrix.

I've never tried for-loops before so I'd appreciate it if anyone knew either how to do that or another efficient way of doing it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

d <- data.frame(
  cond = c("low", "medium", "high"),
  group = c("gr1", "gr2", "gr3"),
  rand = c("yes", "no"),
  trial1 = rnorm(30),
  trial2 = rnorm(30)
)

x <- d %>% 
  group_by(cond, rand, group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    cor_test = map(data, function(i) cor.test(i$trial1, i$trial2)),
    correlation = map_dbl(cor_test, ~ .x$estimate),
    p.value = map_dbl(cor_test, ~ .x$p.value)
  )

x
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   cond   rand  group data             cor_test correlation p.value
#>   <fct>  <fct> <fct> <list>           <list>         <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 low    yes   gr1   <tibble [5 x 2]> <htest>      -0.0329   0.958
#> 2 medium no    gr2   <tibble [5 x 2]> <htest>       0.489    0.403
#> 3 high   yes   gr3   <tibble [5 x 2]> <htest>      -0.413    0.490
#> 4 low    no    gr1   <tibble [5 x 2]> <htest>      -0.240    0.697
#> 5 medium yes   gr2   <tibble [5 x 2]> <htest>      -0.144    0.817
#> 6 high   no    gr3   <tibble [5 x 2]> <htest>       0.0361   0.954
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

1. You first group the data by all combinations of your factor levels
2. Then you "nest" the data, i.e. for each group from step 1, create a "subset" of your data frame and save it in a list-variable called `data` (default name)
3. create a new list-variable, `cor_test`, which saves the result from `cor.test()` calls  using variables `trial1` and `trial2` from each subset
4. create new variables, `correlation` and `p.value`, that simply extract the r (`estimate`) and p (`p.value`) elements from each object saved in the list-variable `cor_test`.

This is a very flexible approach, you just need to define the names of the variables for which you calculate the correlation (`trial1` and `trial2`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but here is how you would estimate a correlation matrix with p-values for each possible combination of the three first variables

```
by(df[,c("trial1","trial2")],list(df$cond,df$group,df$rand),function(x){
  return(list(cor(x),cor.test(x[,1],x[,2])$p.value))
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I've edited my post hoping that I've made it clearer.
I tried your code and it works but I'm not sure how to drop the variables with null values nor how to save it. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Finally someone other than me uses `by`! @Karina, to save results assign an object to `by`. And to remove null, use `Filter`: `Filter(length, mybylistobject)`